# do backlinks from foreigh websites carry value?

Tags: seo, backlinks

For example, links from Spanish websites to an English website, or vice-versa

Spanish page with some English anchor text backlinks, or even an entire English page on an otherwise all Spanish website?

Answer (score 1):

Sure they do. If a site in a different language is linking to yours, and it isn't spammy in nature, it's a vote for a quality page. How much value they give may be different (or not). But as far as I know nothing pertaining to that is known outside of Google. But you could argue that to link to a page in a different language is a strong endorsement of its value if the the two pages are covering related topics.